# Launching another activity from a 'screen pinned' activity

Tags: android, android-manifest, digital-signature, android-screen-pinning

http://florent-dupont.blogspot.ro/2015/02/android-5-screen-pinning.html

> From a pinned app, you cannot start a secondary app, unless this one
>   has the same shared user ID (which means that the sharedUserIdis set
>   in the AndroidManifest.xml and that second application is packaged
>   with the same certificate). Other apps’ Activities won’t be allowed to
>   be started and doing so (by using Context.startActivity()) will simply
>   be ignored.

I have done just those two things above but `startActivity()` is still getting ignored.

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#lockTaskMode:

> If the system is already in lockTask mode when a new task rooted at
>   this activity is launched that task will or will not start depending
>   on whether the package of this activity has been whitelisted.

It looks tome like I have taken the necessary steps for this to work.

Anybody out there who got this working ?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
    mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

    if (!mDpm.isAdminActive(deviceAdmin)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_admin), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (mDpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName()))
    {
        mDpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[]{getPackageName(), "com.that.other.package"});

        try
        {

            enableKioskMode(true);

            PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
            Intent it = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.that.other.package");

            if (null != it) {
                this.startActivity(it);
                Log.d(_TAG, "Started activity for com.that.other.package");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(_TAG, e.getMessage());
            finish();
        }


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_owner), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private void enableKioskMode(boolean enabled) throws Exception
{
    if (enabled)
    {
        if (mDpm.isLockTaskPermitted(this.getPackageName()))
        {
            startLockTask();
            mIsKioskEnabled = true;
            mButton.setText(getString(R.string.exit_kiosk_mode));

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.kiosk_not_permitted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {

        stopLockTask();
        mIsKioskEnabled = false;
        mButton.setText(getString(R.string.enter_kiosk_mode));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your tags, `digital-signature` != `digital-signage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was missing the `android:taskAffinity` tag. Point it to the same strings in both packages and `startActivity()` should start behaving.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you show me a sample code?

Comment: @Meir The sample code is in the question; as for `taskAffinity` check out the docs, it is not hard, just put it in your `<activity>` tags inside the manifest: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff